# skaffold can't find image it has just build

Tags: kubernetes, skaffold

I have the following skaffolding

```
build:
  tagPolicy:
    sha256: {}
  artifacts:
    - image : sdk
      context: docker
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile.sdk
        buildArgs:
          CONFIGURATION: Debug
    - image : app
      context: docker
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile.app
        buildArgs:
          CONFIGURATION: Debug
    - image: azu
      context: rt/azu/src
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile.worker
        buildArgs:
          VERSION : Debug
```

The first two images are built just fine. Whereas the third fails. The second build depends on the first and the third depends on the second. However the third fails with `"MANIFEST_UNKNOWN: manifest unknown"` because it tries to retrieve it from docker hub. If I change the context of the third build to docker (which will make the building of the image fail) skaffold finds the local image. What can I do to keep the correct context and make skaffold aware that it shouldn't pull from docker hub but use the locally build image?

Answer (score 1):

*(Aside: It's difficult to help if you don't include your full `skaffold.yaml` and your `Dockerfile`s.  Just redact pieces that are private.)*

Skaffold "just" orchestrates the builds and has no influence over how the underlying builders resolve images.  But Skaffold *does* instruct the underlying builders how the resulting image should be tagged.  Skaffold provides a set of [*tagging policies*](https://skaffold.dev/docs/pipeline-stages/taggers/).

So it sounds like your `rt/azu/src/Dockerfile.worker` has a `FROM` that is not referencing your `app` image — perhaps the image is being tagged differently than what you're referencing.  Skaffold's default tagger uses the git commit, resulting in image references like `app:v1.12.0-37-g6af3198f3-dirty`.

If my suspicion is true, then you'll want to use the `envTemplate` tagger so that your built images use a more controlled and predictable image tag that you can embed into your `Dockerfile`s.

Comment: The yaml in the question is enough to reproduce the behaviour. There's two errors in skaffold that made this happen. First one is that if the context path doesn't exist skaffold ignores it. When I corrected that mistake skaffold no longer ignored the context but complained that the dockerfile was outside of the context (which is valid for docker and a simple docker buld with the same arguments will succeed)

Comment: I'm glad you figured that out!  I've opened an issue around the lack of an error on an invalid context (https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/issues/4491) — thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `minikube`, delete it and run it again

```bash
minikube delete
minikube start
```